# CakePHP can not find webroot/css/js files

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5, cakephp-2.x

I just download via svn controle version a CakePHP 2.5.2 app to a test server .

After database configuration, the app does not open the css files located at `app/webroot` dir (bootstrap, jquery, main.css).

Is the some aditional config parameter ?

I try changing the owner but did not work.

Comment: Mke sure app/tmp is writable and that debug is at least 2 in /app/Config/core.php `Configure::write('debug', 2);`

Comment: Are they located at app/webroot/css or like u wrote at app/webroot?

Comment: @Yash it is a regular cakephp install nothing special

Comment: @WayNe they are at app/webroot/css . The files are really there

Comment: @InigoFlores debug is already configured to level 2

Comment: Show us  the code how u load the files in your default.ctp

Comment: i am new to cakephp framework how exactly can i show the code you ask ? or default.ctp?
 `echo $this->Html->css(
        array(
            'bootstrap.min',
            'main'
        )
    );
   
    echo $this->fetch('css');    

    echo $this->Html->script(
        array(
            'jquery.min',
            'jquery.mask.min',
        )
    );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a `mod_rewrite` problem.

Make sure you have `.htaccess` in your  `DocumentRoot`, and your Apache server is configured properly.

Everything is described in detail in the CookBook.

[CakePHP 2.x URL Rewriting](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)

---

Edit: As described in the comments, it was solved by the OP by replacing the `Directory` definition in the apache vhost configuration file (`/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf`) with the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/> 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
    AllowOverride FileInfo 
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled checking with apache2ctl -M and these are the rules present in the .htacces: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Solved! after edit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf adding : 
`<Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            # changed from None to FileInfo
            AllowOverride FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>` thank´s for the suppport.

Comment: Yeah! for users wit apache 2.4+ it will be `apache2.conf` or `https.conf`. Follow more instructions from [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html)